# Six word rebuses -- one topic

Tags: word, visual, rebus

Each of these six squares has a solution. Together, they fit under a single theme.

Can you figure out all of the puzzles and name the theme?

[image: Puzzles]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Upper left:

> The Scarlet Letter

Upper middle:

> Invisible Man

Upper right:

> A Tale of Two Cities

Lower left:

> Life of Pi

Lower bottom:

> Fahrenheit 451

Lower right:

> The Color Purple

The theme might be:

> Novels

Comment: Great job! You figured out all of them.

Comment: Yeah, that's obviously better than my answer. Nice work.

Answer (score 3):

Lower left is obviously

> **Life of Pi** - [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Pi) or [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Pi_(film)).

Upper middle seems to be

> **White Man** - [book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/604589.Whiteman) or [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Man_(film)), maybe? - or **Invisible Man**, as suggested by @jafe.

Upper right is

> the letter L highlighted at the intersection of SEOUL and ISTANBUL. Maybe something like **between capitals** or **capital connection**? (Although Istanbul isn't actually a capital any more ... maybe **city connection** then?)

Lower right:

> we just need to figure out what name to use for this colour. Purple square? Mauve square? Lavender square? Or better, **The Colour Purple** - [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Color_Purple) or [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Color_Purple_(film)) (thanks to @hexomino).

I'm thinking the theme might be

> films. Or maybe something more specific, but I'm not seeing the common thread between these specific productions yet.

Comment: Upper middle could be rot13(Vaivfvoyr Zna)?

Comment: Nice work, Rand al'Thor, hexomino, and jafe. You each got figured out part. rot13(Juvgr Zna) is a good alternative answer that also fits the theme.